# Is having a large outlier value going to be a problem for lightgbm?

Tags: python, lightgbm

I have a classification task at hand. I'm using `lightgbm` for that.
I have a particular value that has the histogram as below:

Basically, all values are nicely concentrated on the left, with a few values on the right.
Lightgbm uses approximate splits, rather than exact ones. It, therefore, has to build a histogram and find bin edges.

Does anyone happen to know, how exactly the bin ranges are defined? I'm asking because if one does not choose to build enough bins then it will render the whole variable useless since too much stuff will be cluttered in lower bins. Ultimately, the question is: what are the consequences of having a few very high values in a column?

Also, [this](https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/blob/e95d5ab849f046b8fdf755441e5767094aeb8de2/src/io/bin.cpp#L78) seems to be a relevant piece of code, but I'm not good enough with C++ to read and understand it relatively quickly.

[image]
UPD: Just to clarify, it's a poor visualization here. The largest number is `5.02e03`, not `6265.02e03`

Comment: That's a 6.3e6 value - a very big outlier, indeed.  Is this real data?  How likely is it that those are accurate?  You need to decide if these are errors or something meaningful.

Comment: Yeah, that's a legit thing. It's just a result of dividing a legitimately large number by a legitimately small number, which is also a problem, of course.

Comment: Then you should judge based on the physics or behavior of the system you're measuring.  Maybe you can create bins by temporarily discarding the outlier, assigning bins using that remaining max, and adding the outliers back in to a bin that's > remaining max.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point. I was also considering just clamping it, which would eventually achieve the same result on the lightgbm side, again depending on how they build bin ranges internally. Hence my interest in what would happen in this case

Comment: A couple of nice experiments will give you a good idea of what's going on.